# Ignore duplicates when serializing array with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, serialization, duplicates, json.net

**Clarification** (to anyone in the same situation):

Note that my task is to serialize an existing legacy object. As such, I would prefer to tune the serializer rather than interfere with the data structure.

I believe in most cases it's better to remove the duplicates directly from the data, as indicated by @danny-chen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065993/786559).

---

As part of my object that I want to serialize with JSON.Net, there is a `string[] files` property which contains duplicates:

```
some/path/to/f1.jpg
some/path/to/f1.jpg
some/path/to/f2.jpg
some/path/to/f3.jpg
some/path/to/f2.jpg
```

And let's suppose these are not necessarily in order (`f2, f3, f2`).

Is it possible to serialize the array and ignore the duplicates ? Expected result:

```
{
  "files": [
    "some/path/to/f1.jpg",
    "some/path/to/f2.jpg",
    "some/path/to/f3.jpg"
  ]
}
```

I have tried the `PreserveReferencesHandling` setting, but it didn't work as each `file` in the array is a different object, with a possibly repeated value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to filter the list before serialization as suggested by @Danny Chen.  However, if you absolutely have to do it during serialization you can use a custom `JsonConverter`.

Here is the code you would need:

```
public class RemoveDuplicatesConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IEnumerable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (T item in ((IEnumerable<T>)value).Distinct())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the list or array property in your class for which you'd like to remove duplicates, as shown below.  Be sure the generic type of the converter matches the type of your list.

```
class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("files")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(RemoveDuplicatesConverter<string>))]
    public string[] Files { get; set; }
}
```

Then serialize as normal.  The list in the JSON will have the duplicates removed, but the original list in your object will be unaffected.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_object, Formatting.Indented);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vs2oWQ

Answer (score 6):

It's not part of the serialization, it's part of the data processing. I suggest you remove the duplicates before serialization.

```
string[] files = GetFiles();
data.Files = files.Distinct().ToArray(); 
//serialize data

//instead of data.Files = files; and do tricky things in serialization
```

Comment: yes, that's the obvious and better solution. I wanted to serialize an existing project without interfering with the data structure, simply by adding `[JsonProperty]` on some fields. I will probably refactor to remove duplicates, yes. Thank you!